# How do I use my Stack Overflow account for the rest of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, users, login, stack-exchange

When I go to another Stack Exchange site (e.g., [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour)) and put in my Stack Overflow email/password, it says no such account. However, I somehow have *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* listed under "my communities".

How do I sign up for other Q&A sites and link it to my current account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an account on one Stack Exchange site, you've linked yourself to the network, so you don't have to sign up again on every site.

You do, however, have to log in to create an account and link it to [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current).

To do this, select "log in" instead:

[image: Log in]

Then, select your preferred log in method:

[image: Log in method]

Finally, click "Confirm and Create This Account" to finalize the account:

[image: Confirm and Create This Account]